# Efficiently parsing a CSV file from a web service (using CHSVParser)

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsstring, nsurlrequest

My app is currently parsing CSV files from a web service by using a combination of `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` and `componentsSeparatedByString` methods.
As the files are quite large (> 1 mb on average), parsing takes a couple of seconds on an iPad, which is too slow. The memory footprint of my solution is an issue too (I am holding the full text file in memory).
This is why I am looking for a faster and more memory-efficient solution. I came across `CHCSVParser` which can parse `NSInputStreams` directly, e.g.

```
NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:file]; 
CHCSVParser * p = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithInputStream:stream 
    usedEncoding:&encoding delimiter:';'];
```

*(Source from the sample project on [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser))*

**My question:**

How can I get an `NSInputStream` as the result of an `NSURLRequest`? *(Currently I am getting the whole CSV file as a `NSData` object and converting it to `NSString` in order to parse it).*

Could I use the `NSInputStream` from an `NSURLRequest` directly with `CHSVParser`?

Would you generally recommend using `CHCSVParser`s `initWithInputStream` method with a `NSURLRequest` or rather download the document to memory and parse if after the full download?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by that "`NSInputStream` is an `NSData` object". It isn't. It's an `NSInputStream` object. Also, what's wrong with parsing the string?

Comment: Parsing the string is very slow using the `NSString` based methods.

Comment: Well, parsing is at best linear, don't expect huge data to be parsed quickly using a magical "make me faster" algorithm... Buy a faster CPU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the file to disk using NSURLConnectionDelegate and NSOutputStream (that way you use as little memory as possible while downloading) and then open an NSInputStream to the same file and pass it into CHCSVParser.

Comment: Would it be possible to directly input the stream into CHCSVParser without needing to create a (temporary) file?

Comment: Because you're reading data from a web service, you need to be able to handle HTTP. NSInputStream is lower-level than NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest, and doesn't have any way of dealing with HTTP. The NSURL family of classes provides no way of getting an NSInputSteam to the body of a server response (which is what you would need), so no, you'll either need to create a temporary file or make an in-memory copy of the data.

Comment: What about [AFNetworking`s](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Introduction-to-AFNetworking) streaming capabilities?